# Query different models based on parameter - Refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the moment I have a Slide model which has a layout.

The slide show action renders different things based on the layouts, but each layout needs to query different models.  Currently I have a case statement in my controller to load in the requirements based on what I need.

e.g.

```
def show
  @slide = Slide.find(params[:id]
  case @slide.layout
    when 'products'
      @products = Product.where(display: true)
    when 'strategy'
      @strategy = Strategy.all
    when 'summary'
      @quit_attempt = QuitAttempt.where(user_id: current_user.id)
      @user_products = Product.where(user_id: current_user.id)
      @habits = Habit.all
  end
end
```

Is this the best way to deal with this?  There are far more layouts with different requirements and it's leading to a big controller action.  What else could I do as an alternative.

I guess I could define a method in the model that gets them and pass an array back to the controller, with nil for things that aren't required e.g.

```
@products, @strategy, @habits = @slide.layout_requirements
```

Any advice would be appreciated on how I can refactor this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the cleanest way to do this, but you can try this

define 3 methods in your controller

```
def product_data
  @products = Product.where(display: true)
end

def strategy_data
   @strategy = Strategy.all
end

def summary_data
  @quit_attempt = QuitAttempt.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  @user_products = Product.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  @habits = Habit.all
end
```

And then in show action write as follows

```
def show
  @slide = Slide.find(params[:id]
  eval("#{@slide.layout}_data")
end
```

This should work :)

P.S. Preferably you must find a way out to mode these queries into models. Writing so much of code in controllers is not conventional

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer.  While this would work for my example two above some of the layouts query multiple models, I'll edit to make it clearer.  I was trying to be concise to not overcomplicate things

Comment: I do like that, I think it's far easier to read than a massive case statement.  I think I'll use send rather than eval though.  Thanks.  I'll wait and see what else comes up and if not accept your answer

Comment: +1. I think this is the simplest refactor, and quite clean (apart from `eval`, as mentioned). @Baloo is `Slide.layout` a user-defined field? If so, be sure to run through a whitelist before using `eval` or `send`.

Comment: Just wanted to know, what could be other way to do this if we dont use eval, do we write it as `send("#{@slide.layout}_data")` ?

Comment: @DamienRoche - It's user selected drop down from admin which I validate to ensure it's included in an array of acceptable values (the same array I use to populate the select).

Comment: @Himesh yes, exactly that.  Although I have `send("#{@slide.layout}_data") if respond_to?("#{@slide.layout}_data")` as some of the layouts don't require additional data.